# preg_replace phone number sanitizing for international numbers

Tags: php, preg-replace, substr

I have a snip of PHP code that we use to strip out spaces and non numericals from phone numbers in PHP which works great and it removes the leading 0 from the phone number as well:

```
substr(preg_replace('/[^0+a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '', $phone), 1);
```

However in some scenarios the leading number is not a 0 it will be a 1 and we don't want them stripped.

so if the number was 0312345678 it needs the leading 0 stripped off
If the number however was 1800123456 it should not strip the leading 1 from the number

how can I adjust the replace to not strip all 1st digits off and only strip it off if its a 0, while retaining the remaining preg_replace functions as currently using substr strips the first digit regardless of what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
$phone = preg_replace('/^0|[^a-zA-Z0-9+]+/', '', $phone)
```

The regex will remove a `0` at the start of string with the `^0` alternative, and the `[^a-zA-Z0-9+]+` will remove any one or more chars other than ASCII letters, digits and `+` anywhere else in the string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wUvEoi/1).

Comment: It is not completely valid, it accepts many "+" chars and not leading only. For example "1+2+3+4+5+6" is valid.

Comment: @Tobia The regex above is tailored for the specific scenario OP shared. For your case, you can use `^0+|[^\na-zA-Z0-9+]+|(?<=\S)\+`. Or `^0+|[^\na-zA-Z0-9+]+|(?!^)\+`